# The total discount per month, year and currency, excluding data from 2017

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to know the total discount per month, year and currency, excluding data from 2017 for this database:

```
Sales table:
PK sale_id : text
FK1 client_id : text
tax_code : text
currency : text
amount : integer
notes : text
created_at : timestamp

Sales_entries table:
PK sale_entry_id : text
FK1 sale_id : text
price : integer
discount : integer
FK2 journey_id : text
```

I have created this query but I don't know if it's correct:

```
Select
Datetrunc(‘month’, a.created_at) as month,
Datetrunc(‘year’, a.created_at) as year,
a.Currency as currency,
Sum(b.discount) as discount
From sales as a
Left join sales_entries as b 
On a.sales_id = b.sale_id
Where year <> 2017
Group by
Month,
Year,
currency
```

Comment: Please enter some sample data and the desired output.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (Some product specific functionality used there.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your date arithmetic is a bit off.  I think this is what you want:

```
select year(s.created_at) as yyyy,
       month(s.created_at) as mm,
       s.Currency as currency,
       sum(se.discount) as discount
from sales s left join
     sales_entries se
     on s.sales_id = se.sale_id
where s.created_at < '2017-01-01' or
      s.created_at >= '2018-01-01'
group by year(s.created_at), month(s.created_at),
         s.currency
order by year(s.created_at), month(s.created_at), s.currency;
```

Notice that I also replaced the table aliases with meaningful abbreviations rather than arbitrary letters.

Comment: plus one for the changed where clause, so an index on created_at can be used (if defined of course).

Answer (score 0):

With the same database, this would be correct for the total sale amount per month, year, and currency. That amount should be divided by 100 and truncated to one decimal.

```
select year(s.created_at) as yyyy,
       month(s.created_at) as mm,
       s.Currency as currency,
      truncate(sum(se.amount)/100,1) as totamount
FROM sales s
```